# Why does the setter that takes a function returned by useState execute twice on a single call using React?

Tags: reactjs

Say you have the following state

```
const [elements, setElements] = React.useState([]);
```

The weird thing I noticed is when using the setter that takes a function, it seems to execute the console log twice and I don't know why. Any explanations?

```
const handleAddClick = (e) => {
    console.log("button clicked");
    setElements((elems) => {
      console.log("set elements called");
      return [...elems, "abc"];
    });
  };
```

**Output**

```
button clicked
set elements called
set elements called
```

Comment: That should not happen - show the full code please ^^

Comment: @moonwave99 According to documentation for strict mode, this is a completely valid scenario - `State updater functions (the first argument to setState)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to [`StrictMode`](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects).

In the list of `StictMode` actions it includes:

> State updater functions (the first argument to setState)

In strict mode, state updater functions may be called twice to catch side effects. If your updater function is pure, it will not cause any issues - and the double update will not happen in production.

If your updater function mutates state, you will see odd behavior and it will help identify a bug.

Comment: Why doesn't it run two times in the first click? https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-bird-tt0hmu?file=/src/App.js

Comment: This was it, thank you! I thought that was only the case for useEffects. Always learning something new about React every day :)

Comment: @Konrad That is also a good follow up, in NextJS 13 it does it twice in strict mode each time, but in the playground it does it twice only after the first click haha so confusing

Comment: @Konrad I am on a work computer that blocks codesandbox so I can't view that right now. I am confident that this is the cause, but I also have not spent time researching exactly how and when StrictMode works in every scenario. Honestly I don't feel the need to. I understand why these extra side effects can happen, and that's enough for any practical needs.

Comment: Updated language to be less absolute, since it sounds like you have discovered cases where it does not happen every time